# Xcode 7 ERROR ITMS-90474: "Invalid Bundle", can't submit to Apple

Tags: xcode, xcode7, bundle

I have an app I'm trying to submit to Apple.  I've already validated it. I'm using Xcode 7 and Swift 2.  When I try to submit to Apple, I get the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90474: "Bundle Invalid. iPad Multitasking support requires
>   there orientations:
>   'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIIinterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'.
>   Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait' in bundle.

What do I do?  Do I make some images with the names they ask for?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Checking `Requires full screen`  under Deployment Info in `Project's General tab` will solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: What is the significance of choosing this option? I mean, the original error does not have any mention of requiring full screen

Comment: @ShravyaBoggarapu iPad multitasking implies sharing the screen with another app. Saying "requires full screen" is like saying don't support multitasking.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it has the side-effect of removing the status bar from the app.  I tried instead to check all Orientations as supported and manage orientation using the supportedInterfaceOrientations method, but ran into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782044/ios-9-supportedinterfaceorientations-not-working

Comment: ITMS 90474 and also ITMS 90475, both were resolved by the above.

Comment: Dimitris, it is great but how can solve this issue without loosing multitasking support?

Answer (score 12):

ERROR ITMS-90474 & ITMS-90475 in Xcode  Archive Submission failed
ERROR ITMS-90474 : Xcode 7 shows error in Archive Submission

**Error Screen (ERROR ITMS-90474 & ITMS-90475)**

[image: ERROR ITMS-90474 & ITMS-90475]

**Solution for ERROR ITMS-90474 & ITMS-90475:**

[image]

**Guidelines**

From Xcode project,
TARGETS >> - iOS >> General >> Deployment Info >> In iPad,
If you tick (Requires full screen) option , it is OK!

Answer (score 8):

TARGETS >  iOS > General > Deployment Info > Select  "iPad" tab

,Then Check 『Requires full screen』

from http://nijoen.net/blog/261/

Comment: By the way, some way if you have problem with ERROR ITMS-90475

Answer (score 6):

Instead of changing the status bar setting, you can actually just follow the instructions from apple and support all 4 orientations in iPad section of settings. I had disabled upside-down, and simply enabling upside-down fixed the issue. Apple seems to want apps to run upside down, so we might as well support that.

Answer (score 1):

Did some research and noticed I had my universal app `Device Orientation` set to portrait.  I had unchecked `Landscape Left`, `Landscape Right`, and `Upside Down`.  Selected those and all set now.

Comment: then also its give error at upload time @ChallengerGuy